# Add multiple value of query parameter react router browerhistory

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router to change url as below.

```
browserHistory.push({ pathname: npathname, query: {
    checkin : checkin,
    checkout : checkout,
    managed_by : 'Owner',
    managed_by : 'Manager',
} });
```

As you see here I want to pass 2 values of query parameter, but it overwrites the first value by second. How can I pass both the values of query parameter?

Comment: Have you tried making `managed_by` an array like so: `managed_by: ['Owner', 'Manager']`?

Comment: Works, great thanks.

Comment: Can u write in answer so I can mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `managed_by` property as an array like this:

```
browserHistory.push({ pathname: npathname, query: {
    checkin : checkin,
    checkout : checkout,
    managed_by : ['Owner','Manager']
} });
```